# Detect when url containing local anchor tag is clicked on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to detect when a url with local anchor tag is clicked on `html` page which is current been rendered on `UIWebView`. I have done lots of searches around and implemented various workarounds but no success. The ultimate suggestion from all around always comes to this `delegate` method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

The biggest problem what I concluded was that this method simply doesn't get called for local anchor tags if already in a rendered `HTML` page. What i mean is if fresh new page `URL (anchor tag)` included is clicked that method gets fired. Here is an example. If i my `UIWebView` has already rendered `www.xyz.com`, now if i press some url which is like `www.xyz.com#amazing` (link present on that same page) then delegate method doesn't get fired.

I was developing a simple `in-app` browser. I had to show `URL` of every page been `rendered/visible` at address box of my in-app browser. Only obstacle now is i cannot show every anchor `tags/javascript` links that just brings new content but same `URL` domain.

There were solutions regarding usage of this

```
`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.hash"]`
```

Problem is that until and unless if I can't get `delegate` method `called/fired` than there is no benefit of this code.

Is there any workaround or shall I just give up on this? I hope I am clear with explaining the problem.

**Note: Best TestCase Scenario is mobile version pinterest.com on UIWebView**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly follow what you're trying to do, perhaps you could clarify a bit more.

In the meantime, here's how to get your UIWebView to handle every link click in the web page it has loaded.  It's looking for a URL Scheme that begins with "bloodwing".  If it finds it, it will stop the request.  Otherwise, it will work as expected.

So `http://www.yahoo.com` will work, and `bloodwing://www.yahoo.com` will fail.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;

    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString: @"bloodwing"]) {
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"doSomething();"];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES; // Return YES to make sure regular navigation works as expected.
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi, That is what i explained later that this delegate method doesn't get fired for anchor based link navigation. Check the Pinterest mobile version site on UIWebview. wwww.yahoo.com#science won't work if you are already on www.yahoo.com

Comment: Anchor links probably do not trigger the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType: event.  It would make sense that they don't – that isn't external navigation, it's internal navigation within the same page.  Think of it from the standpoint of a normal browser, an anchor is handled locally by the browser – there's no web server involved.  In the case of a UIWebView the "web server" is your .m class.

Comment: Hi. I understand. Do you think there is any workaround? Some website use internal navigation like they bring new <DIV> and load the dynamic content there from ajax etc. It would be really helpful if there was any hack around. In the end i guess if this is the way it is then i may have to give up. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my example code above.  With the combination of custom URL Schemes and `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` you should be able to do everything you want.  Change the anchor links to normal links with your custom scheme.  Have your ViewController class send back whatever JavaScript is necessary to update the HTML (add divs, change images, etc.)  The page won't reload and you'll get the affect you desire.

Comment: Thanks, My problem is different. I am not looking for custom scheme url. Since i am developing in-app browser where user will be browsing any website and want to show change in any url at my address box even if its local anchor url. Hence i can't be tracking or changing anchor tags on those websites.

Comment: In that case you'll need to inject some custom JavaScript into the web page after your UIWebView loads it that rewrites anchor tags to be the custom format we discuss above.  It doesn't matter what page is loaded in the UIWebView, if your custom JS can go thru and rewrite the anchors you're golden.

Comment: Thanks. I can inject the custom js and even maybe rewrite the anchor. But it comes back to same concern will that above delegate method be fired ? If your thinking around scheme url then it will always fire but will normal tags will fire. In the end its just the name thats changed. And i need that delegate method to get called where i will be doing processing with any info i got.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65223/discussion-between-axeva-and-bloodwing).